# PostgreSQL explain datetime timezone conversion

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm saving to db DateTime like:

```
  2019-02-25T11:30:26+03:00
```

Then in DB it looks like this:

```
  2019-02-25 08:30:26.000000 +00:00
```

Converted to UTC. OK.
And then, when I want to get this DateTime back in local time I have to

```
  .annotate(check_time_local=Trunc('check_time', 'second', tzinfo=timezone('Etc/GMT+3')))
```

which will be converted to a query like:

```
  DATE_TRUNC('second', "table"."dt_field" AT TIME ZONE '-03') AS "check_time_local"
```

And getting from DB:

```
  2019-02-25 11:30:26
```

In Django:

```
  2019-02-25 11:30:26 -0300
```

Why not +3? Why -3?

Comment: What is the data type of the column in postgres?  Is it timestamp or timestamptz?  I'm guessing it's timestamp, but should really be timestamptz.

Comment: timestamp with time zone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out this is the tz database identifiers of the form Etc/GMT±* deliberately have an inverted sign than the usual forms we expect under ISO 8601. That is, they are in terms of positive values being West of GMT, rather than positive values being East of GMT

More details here:

[Time zones `Etc/GMT`, why it is other way round?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53076575/time-zones-etc-gmt-why-it-is-other-way-round)