# Deal with CEST tz with as.POSIXct

Tags: r, datetime, timezone

I have this df

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, Timestamp = c("2022-08-09 22:01:45 UTC", "2022-08-09 22:01:56 UTC", "2022-08-09 22:02:04 UTC")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

I would like to extract day to another column

Used this

```
mutate(Day = as.POSIXct(strftime(Timestamp, format="%Y-%m-%d"),  format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

But I got this

```
Timestamp           Day                
   <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1 2022-08-09 22:01:45 2022-08-10 00:00:00
 2 2022-08-09 22:01:56 2022-08-10 00:00:00
 3 2022-08-09 22:02:04 2022-08-10 00:00:00
```

I would like to get this

```
Timestamp           Day                
   <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1 2022-08-09 22:01:45 2022-08-09 00:00:00
 2 2022-08-09 22:01:56 2022-08-09 00:00:00
 3 2022-08-09 22:02:04 2022-08-09 00:00:00
```

My current time

```
as.POSIXct(Sys.Date(), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" , optional = FALSE)
"2022-08-12 02:00:00 CEST"
```

I think I should deal with UTC and CEST time zone, but don't know how.

```
mutate(Day = as.POSIXct(strftime(Timestamp, format="%Y-%m-%d", tz = "CEST"),  format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

doesn't work.

Comment: The langauge of dates and datetimes is complex.  When you say "day", what do you mean?  The date part of the date time?  The day of the week or month? And do you also need to convert the UTC timezone of your input to CEST?  (So that  "2022-08-09 22:01:45 UTC" becomes - I think - "2022-08-10 00:01:45 CEST"?)  It would be *really* helpful to see your **expected** output.

Comment: I just edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CET and CEST are defined via `tz = "etc/GMT-1"` and `tz = "etc/GMT-2"` respectively. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53076575/time-zones-etc-gmt-why-it-is-other-way-round) to find out why.

I'm not 100 % sure if I get your issue, but if it's only that you need `Day` to be in CEST instead of UTC, you can make use of `lubridate::with_tz()` followed by `format()` to specify the format of your timestamps to be displayed.

```r
stamp_utc <- "2022-08-09 22:01:45 UTC"

stamp_cest <- stamp_utc |> strptime(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC") |> lubridate::with_tz("etc/GMT-2") 
stamp_cest
#> [1] "2022-08-10 00:01:45 +02"

day_cest <- format(stamp_cest, "%Y-%m-%d")
day_cest
#> [1] "2022-08-10"

# transfered to your dplyr pipe
df |> dplyr::mutate(Day = strptime(Timestamp, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC") |> lubridate::with_tz("etc/GMT-2") |> format("%Y-%m-%d"))
#>   ID               Timestamp        Day
#> 1  1 2022-08-09 22:01:45 UTC 2022-08-10
#> 2  2 2022-08-09 22:01:56 UTC 2022-08-10
#> 3  3 2022-08-09 22:02:04 UTC 2022-08-10
```

Comment: Ok, since you edited your expected output, dismiss the `lubridate::with_tz()` part and continue to work with your timestamps after `tz = "UTC"` definition inside of `strptime()`.

Comment: Yeah this is my problem. If stamp_utc is "2022-08-09 22:01:45 UTC" I would like to have "2022-08-09" in my Day variable. Not "2022-08-10".

Comment: but tz = "etc/GMT-2" works well. Thank you